# Fancytree properties for setting maxHeight, minHeight

Tags: fancytree

I want to give maxHeight and minHeight like below to my fancytree.

```
 $("#tree").fancytree({
        checkbox: true,
        selectMode: 3,
        autoSize: false,
        fitToView: false,
        minHeight: 300,
        maxHeight: 600,
        source: {
            url: '@Url.Action("GetTerritories1", "Step1")',
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data)
            {

            },
            error:function(data, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {alert(thrownError);}
        },
        lazyLoad: function(event, data){
            // we can't return values from an event handler, so we
            // pass the result as `data`attribute.
            // alert('lazy call');
            data.result = $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetTerritories1", "Step1")',
                data: {mode: "children", nodeid: data.node.key}
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I have gone through the documentation but could not determine if this is possible. Would there be another way to do this if not?

Comment: are you trying to apply `minHeight` and `maxHeight` on the `#tree` ?

Comment: I want to apply similar to that. My question is that whether we can use such kind of properties as I didnt see any such properties. I want them atleast workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

So `fancytree` is a jQuery plugin that I'm assuming you downloaded from this [Github Project](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree). There is some documentation, but as it is an Open Source project learning the project is really what you have to task yourself with. Usually learning the ins and outs is how to go.

Based on your question.

No. These [options](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/global.html#FancytreeOptions) are the only options that are able to be used with `fancytree`. Depending on what you want to achieve it is possible to apply a `min-width` or `min-height` to an element via CSS or Javascript in almost any scenario. If you would like to make it more clear I can potentially provide an example of this, but as of now you cannot use options for this.

It may be a good idea to open an issue with the project on Github and request this as a functionality. You can open an issue by creating an account and going [here](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues). If the author or other contributors like your idea and it is well explained they may help you out!

Comment: Thank you I raised it on Github. But I managed these via div properties itself. Thank you for your help.

Comment: maybe you can post an answer with your workaround since there isn't options and it will make it possible for other to learn from what you decided was best! Glad you worked it out.